# JSF: Datatable is not updating

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am learning JSF and stuck on the below problem:

Xhtml class:

```
    <h:form><p:inputText  value="#{tempView.tempName}" e:placeholder="Search Name">
    </p:inputText>
    <p:commandButton id="search" value="Search" action="#{tempView.searchName()}" update="dataTable">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton value="clear" action="#{tempView.clearSearchCriteria()}" update="dataTable">
    </p:commandButton>


<p:dataTable id="dataTable"
    value="#{tempView.tmpList}"
    var="tempVar" rowStyleClass="#{tempView.rowStyleClass(tempVar)}"
    rows="12" paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink}
    {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" scrollable="true">

    <p:column headerText="First Name" sortBy="#{tempVar.firstName}">
        <h:outputText value="#{tempVar.firstName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Last Name" sortBy="#{tempVar.lastName}">
        <h:outputText value="#{tempVar.lastName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Institute / Practice Name" sortBy="#{tempVar.Address}">
        <h:outputText value="#{tempVar.instituteName}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Java Class:

```
public String searchName() {

    System.out.println("Executed");


    /**

        logic of refining list..
    **/
```

}

The issue I am facing is..first it is calling the getter and setter method and then action 'searchName' and after executing the action method. it is not calling the getter and setter due to that my datatable is not updating.
The action method 'searchName' have the logic of refining the list in datatable.
Please let me know if you need any other information.
Thanks.

Comment: do you mean that the data in your datatable are not updated when you call the searchName method ?

Comment: Hamaza: yes, data is not updating :/

Comment: could you show more of your datatable and searchName method code ?

Comment: Please add more code. Do you have form tag ?

Comment: Do you get any errors in console ?

Comment: Makky: updated the code

Comment: Desaretiuss: Nope, even I am putting simple sysout statement it is executing getter and setter first and than action method and it's not calling getter setter again.

Comment: Use actionlistener instead of action... You will need to change method in your bean too .

Comment: @Makky:  Thanks, ActionListener solves the problem. So what I understood is ActionListener should be use for UI components and Action is used for navigation on different page

Comment: @Damon I have give this as an answers accept it as may be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Action , use `ActionListener`. You will need to change the method in your bean to return void and add `ActionEvent` as paramter.